# Securing and storing Active Directory logs

Tags: windows, logging, active-directory

If we plan to log script block logging, module logging and transcription logs in Active Directory using group policy, what/where is the best place to secure these logs so we can be assured of their integrity?

Comment: Send it to Syslog or SIEM

Answer (score 1):

A centralized logging server like a SIEM which has regular backups would be a great place to start. This would also allow you to more easily analyze these logs for anomalies versus reading the raw event logs. There are a variety of open source solutions that cost no money that can perform this task.